# Aggregate pathological case of empty data.frame/data.table as if it had data

Tags: r, aggregate

When aggregating data, I can find the unique instances of values in one column which correspond to another:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  w = sample(c("a","b","c"), 8, replace = TRUE),
  x = sample(1:10, 8, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 8, replace = TRUE)
)
summary <- aggregate(. ~ y, data, unique, simplify=FALSE)
```

This produces a simple summary:

> ```
> > summary
>     y       w                 x
> 1  no       2                10
> 2 yes 1, 3, 2 2, 3, 1, 5, 10, 6
> ```

However, when the input dataframe happens to be empty:

```
data <- data.frame(
  w = sample(c("a","b","c"), 0, replace = TRUE),
  x = sample(1:10, 0, replace=TRUE),
  y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 0, replace = TRUE)
)
summary <- aggregate(. ~ y, data, unique, simplify=FALSE)
```

the code breaks:

> ```
> Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
>   no rows to aggregate
> ```

How can I achieve this output I would expect:

> ```
> > summary
> [1] y w x
> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> > class(summary$y)
> [1] "factor"
> > class(summary$w)
> [1] "list"
> > class(summary$x)
> [1] "list"
> ```

(This allows down-stream code to work whether or not there happens to be any data to process.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `purrr` package in the `tidyverse` ecosystem has functions to handle pathological cases when you're iterating over lists. This is a good use case for `possibly`. This (along with `safely` and `quietly`) is an adverb, because it's a function that modifies another function, so that's why the syntax looks a little unusual.

```
library(purrr)
safe_aggregate <- possibly(aggregate, otherwise = data.frame())

safe_aggregate(.~Sepal.Length, head(iris, 10), unique, simplify = F)
```

> ```
>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
> 1          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2       1
> 2          4.6    3.1, 3.4     1.5, 1.4    0.2, 0.3       1
> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       1
> 4          4.9    3.0, 3.1     1.4, 1.5    0.2, 0.1       1
> 5          5.0    3.6, 3.4     1.4, 1.5         0.2       1
> 6          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       1
> 7          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       1
> ```

```
safe_aggregate(.~Sepal.Length, head(iris, 0), unique, simplify = F)
```

> ```
> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
> ```

Updated to include a narrow view of error handling for this particular case:

```
safe_aggregate <- function(dat) {
    if(nrow(dat)==0) {
      return(dat)
    } else {
      aggregate(.~y, dat, unique)
    } 
}
```

Comment: The result has lost the columns as well as the rows.

Comment: If you know the columns ahead of time, you can put them into the `otherwise=` argument. Beyond, that you can wrap it in a function, like `safe_aggregate<-function(dat){if(nrow(dat)==0) {return(dat)} else {aggregate(.~y, dat, unique)} }`

Comment: This feels really close to what I'm looking for. I've added the types I expect in the columns (the order of the columns does not matter).

Comment: I'm going to see if I can get by without 'proper' types for the time being.

Comment: Is there a reason you write "return" in the first case but not the second?

Comment: Re: `return` vs no `return`. It's just a stylistic habit when I'm doing error checking and returning a single named object, to make sure the function exits as soon as it finds an exit condition. I don't think there's any practical reason to do one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Brian's edited answer, I used a wrapper to the the aggregate function which returns a 0-row `data.frame`. However, all aggregate arguments are passed dynamically to the wrapper function for re-usability and the output `data.frame` when input is empty is formatted as I expect: 0 rows with as many columns as are mentioned in the formula.

```
safe_aggregate <- function(data_colnames, groupping_colnames, df, fun, ...) {
      
  # Input df has 0 rows: return empty dataframe with expected column names and types
  if(nrow(df) == 0) {
    
    df_out <- df # Copy input df
    df_out[, !(colnames(df) %in% c(data_colnames, groupping_colnames))] <- NULL # Remove columns that are not part of formula
    
  # Generic case: call aggregate function
  } else {
    
    # LEFT SIDE VARIABLE(S): name output columns
    
    out_data_colnames <- list()
    out_data_colnames[data_colnames] <- df[, data_colnames, drop = FALSE]
    
    # RIGHT SIDE VARIABLE(S): name output columns

    out_groupping_colnames <- list()
    out_groupping_colnames[right_colnames] <- df[, groupping_colnames, drop = FALSE]
    
    # Actually call aggregate function

    df_out <- aggregate(out_data_colnames,
                        out_groupping_colnames,
                        fun,
                        ...)
    
  } 
  
  return(df_out)
  
}
```

Usage: `summary <- aggregate(. ~ y, data, unique)` would become `summary <- safe_aggregate(c('x', 'w'), 'y', data, unique)`. One disadvantage of this method is the loss of flexibility of the dot notation, as all variables must be specified individually by name.

Comment: Can you update your answer to use the y, w, and x from the question? I'm confused what left and right variable names are. (It's been a while since I used the aggregate function!)

Comment: I have edited my answer so that the example of the function matches your column names, sorry for the previous mistake. I have changed the function arguments to data_colnames (name(s) of df column(s) that are to be summarised) and grouping_colnames (name(s) of df column(s) used as grouping variable(s)), I hope this is more self-explanatory.